# Finding matrices that satisfy equation

Tags: matrices, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation

I am trying to find the set of square matrices that satisfy:
$$M=M^{2n-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{2n-2}{M^k}$$
$$n\in \mathbb{N}$$
I have tried simplifying and trying to treat the sum as a geometric series but this hasn't lead me anywhere. How could I go about solving this?.

Comment: is $n$ the size of the square matrix, as in $M_{nn} \; ? \;$

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about fully describing the set of matrices with this property. But we can use the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem to know that if $p(\lambda)$ is the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A$, then $p(A)=0$. If you consider all matrices $M$ with characteristic polynomials $p$ which divide polynomial $q$ given by $$q(\lambda)= \lambda^{2n-1}-2\lambda - \sum_{k=2}^{2n-2}\lambda^k$$
Then $q(M)=0$ and we can rewrite the equation to infer that $q(M)=0$ implies that
$$M=M^{2n-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}M^k$$
So if you are attempting to find matrices such that $q(M)$ is equal to $0$, you can form a polynomial $p$ by taking $n$ distinct roots (including multiplicities) of $q$. This will give you the eigenvalues of a matrix. Then you just need to construct a matrix with those eigenvalues. This will at least give you a subset and I am not sure if it will fully describe all matrices in the set.